# Not able to complete Magento 2 installation

Tags: magento2

During Magento 2 installation it reach 65% and stuck with below error:

Installing user configuration...

```
[ERROR] Exception: Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_dut4kvc67t0gvapfoo399b65d1, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)..
```

permission is 777 to var folder, i'm using plesk 12.5.30 with php 7

what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your `session.save_handler` PHP parameter is set to some another session storage than `files` (for example, `redis`, `memcached`, and so on). This is a known issue we’re working to resolve.
For More detail see [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_session.html)

For Directory Permission [see here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html)

Comment: my session.save_handler is set to files, pls see http://herara.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: Please upgrade your magento 2 code.It will solve your problem, Please read the given link

Comment: no success, i've noticed this error only after upgrade php on centos 7 from 5.4 to 5.6

Comment: Make sure your /var folder should have write permission.

Comment: as mentioned in my question all proper permission applied

Comment: I got a 404 on your phpinfo.php link. If the value is set to outside the Magento file system, you must set permissions on the directory specified by `session.save_handler`. I ran into this before.

Comment: @Arunendra: From Magento 2.0.6, directories and files permissions are no longer supposed to be our concernation. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/116471/18821

Comment: you need to change owner of  directory /var/lib/php/session  to webserver owner name for example httpd means change owner "apache ".

Comment: @AhmadDarwish Did you eventually solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix you can set `app/etc/env.php` like so:

```
array (
  'save' => 'files',
  'save_path' => '/tmp',
),
```

`tmp` is always readble and writable by everyone.

It is clearly a permissions issue. Espescially when running with `nginx` and `php-fpm`

Answer (score -1):

I believe the correct permissions are 0770
<strike>And the owner should be the web server, in my case: nginx
chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/session</strike>

Since my original posting I have determined the actual problem is the php upgrades.
When php is upgraded, the owner is changed to 'apache' which is php's default setting.

This is a known issue and causes problems to any one whose web server is not 'apache'.  Until such time as php recognizes the there is life beyond apache and leaves the 'owner' as is if it exists, this is going to cause problems.

Solution:

- If you don't have an 'apache' user/group then add it: useradd -s /sbin/nologin apache
- Make 'apache' the owner: chown -R apache:apache /var/lib/php/session
- Add your web user to the apache group: gpasswd -a psacln apache
- For others: gpasswd -a [web-user] apache eg. gpasswd -a nginx apache

The next time php is upgraded you won't find your site inaccessible.
I suspect this will be addressed by php at some point but it hasn't been as of this week.

I don't understand why MagenX didn't provide an explanation and solution rather than a somewhat meaningless comment.

Comment: as you know in plesk the owner will be psacln and can not be nginx or apache

Comment: this will be overridden when you upgrade php