# What Are the Final Production File Permissions for Magento 2.0.6

Tags: file-permissions, magento-2.0.6

pretty much what the title says

the link at the bottom of this page
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

for file permissions doesnt work

there is something about file permissions in the update

I fish out what the link goes to and i guess it is supposed to go here

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

where this is documentation on shared hosting, and dual user hosting, but i run a private server, and the documentation has 0 to go on even though it says there is a spot on that page for it

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Magento 2.0.6, Magento provides a more flexible way for you to set file ownership and permissions. Instead of setting permissions explicitly, you only need to make sure files and directories are writable for installation.

Basically, it depends on `umask` of your system. By default, the `umask` is 002, which means that directories have 775 permissions and files have 664 permissions.

But from Magento 2.0.6, you can set YOUR OWN directory & file permission by creating a file name `magento_umask` inside your Magento root.

For eg: I want Magento directories have 755 permissions and files have 644 permission, I will put 022 into my `magento_umask`

For more information about `umask`: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Comment: I operate my own private server so i can just chmod i was just curious.  I have read production values should be 640 for file and 750 for directories, but that isnt for magento 2.0.6, i realize they arent that much different there was just something in the update about file permissions

Comment: @Chris: That is hardcoded by Magento from previous version. And that is also our headache for a decade (file and folder permission always be back to the hardcoded one after you execute `magento setup:static-content:deploy`). Welcome to Magento 2 world.

Comment: I just wish they could fix the web page that i cited with the broken link for permissions after installation

Comment: @Chris: Can you consider to accept this answer as solution. And welcome aboard :)

Comment: they actually fixed the web page, so the correct answer in my mind is go to the web page honestly.  if you could edit your answer to cite the actual page here(I cant edit) I will accept  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html

Comment: also this is only for a one user system as i am a private server i have a two user system magentouser and apache, so the correct answer for me is on the previous page http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok because I went to github for magento's dev docs located [here](https://github.com/magento/devdocs/)

I made an issue specifically regarding these issues and now there is a very easily found page [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html)

for production file permissions and what to do to set them